# How to git pull using aws code deploy

Tags: aws-code-deploy

Suppose we already have:

1. Existing infrastructure with few instances in a load balancer
2. Existing github account and application already deployed in the instances

How can I achieve following using aws code-deploy?

We have multiple commits since last pull to production servers, how can we achieve git pull on production multiple instances using code-deploy.

1. Pull out an instance from load balancer
2. git pull
3. restart/reload server
4. instance Add instance again to the load balancer

Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

CodeDeploy gives you the option for deploying an application directly from [Github](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ-tutorial.html).

If you need to build your code before deploying or you are not willing to introduce appspec file in the github repo, you can create a different deployable bundle and put all the commands to pull / build, attach / detatch from load balancer, etc in the hook scripts.

In case you are using AWS Elastic load balancing, we have some sample [scripts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/elastic-load-balancing-integ.html) you can borrow from: 
I hope this helps you get set up.

Thanks,
Amartya Datta Gupta